# Understanding how owning side in a bidirectional relationship works

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I'm validating a project schema using `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate` task (codes aren't mine I'm just trying to get this works fine). One of the common messages I can see is this one:

> - The field Mapyet\AfiliadoBundle\Entity\Widget#negocio is on the owning side of a bi-directional relationship, but the specified
>     mappedBy association on the target-entity
>     Mapyet\AfiliadoBundle\Entity\Negocio# does not contain the required
>     'inversedBy' attribute.

This is how `$negocio` is defined at `Widget.php` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Negocio", mappedBy="widget")
 */
private $negocio;
```

This is how `$widget` is defined at `Negocio.php` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Widget", inversedBy="negocio")
 */
private $widget;
```

What is wrong in that definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inverse them :

**Widget.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Negocio", inversedBy="widget")
 */
private $negocio;
```

**Negocio.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Widget", mappedBy="negocio")
 */
private $widget;
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: This one `AnnotationException: [Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\OneToMany declared on property Mapyet\AfiliadoBundle\Entity\Negocio::$widget does not have a property named "inversedBy". Available properties: mappedBy, targetEntity, cascade, fetch, orphanRemoval, indexBy`

Comment: @ReynierPM so maybe try to execute `rm -rf app/cache/dev` and run `./app/console d:s:v` again. Your code looks ok.

Comment: Really rare this, now Profiler say this `The association Mapyet\AfiliadoBundle\Entity\Negocio#widget refers to the inverse side field Mapyet\AfiliadoBundle\Entity\Widget#negocios which does not exist.`

Comment: it's maybe because of the typo `negocio` without `s` not `negocios`